# Can't use extensions with GraphQLError

Tags: exception, error-handling, graphql, apollo-server

From the Apollo Graphql document, this way can define extension error:

> https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/

```js
    import { GraphQLError } from 'graphql';

    throw new GraphQLError('the error message', 
      extensions: {
        code: 'SOMETHING_BAD_HAPPENED',
        http: {
          status: 404,
          headers: new Map([
            ['some-header', 'it was bad'],
            ['another-header', 'seriously'],
          ]),
        },
      },
    );
```

But in my case it got this error:

```
Argument of type '{ extensions: { code: string; http: { status: number; headers: Map<string, string>; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Maybe<ASTNode | readonly ASTNode[]>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'extensions' does not exist in type 'ASTNode | readonly ASTNode[]'.

 23         extensions: {
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 24           code: 'SOMETHING_BAD_HAPPENED',
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
 31           },
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
 32         },
    ~~~~~~~~~

Found 1 error(s).
```

I'm using these packages:

- "apollo-server-core": "^3.7.0",
- "apollo-server-express": "^3.4.0",
- "apollo-server-plugin-base": "^0.13.0",

I also tried to install `apollo-server-testing` but still can't use extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to encapsulate the second argument with an object. `{ extensions }`

Do this:

```js
throw new GraphQLError('the error message', 
{ // curly bracket here to open the object
  extensions: {
    code: 'SOMETHING_BAD_HAPPENED',
    http: {
      status: 404,
      headers: new Map([
        ['some-header', 'it was bad'],
        ['another-header', 'seriously'],
      ]),
    },
  },
} // curly bracket here to close the object
);
```

Also, @Alpin Cleopatra answer works because of the constructor overload, but it's not intended to be used this way.

See the two signatures here:
[image]

Comment: I tried the code above (which is the also the same as the code in apollo-server documentation) but I'm getting the same error mentioned in this post. Only the comment below worked with the null options and I don't think it's okay to use it. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

This way works:

```
  throw new GraphQLError('the error message',
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    {
      code: 'SOMETHING_BAD_HAPPENED',
      http: {
        status: 404,
      },
    },
  );
```

Comment: Make sure you're using `graphql` >= 16. I forgot to run `yarn install`, so I had v15 installed, which is why I was seeing this error.

Comment: that is some unpleasing code but it actually works LOL

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I have to stick with `graphql@15`, with the answers above, I create an extended GraphQLError class:

```
// backend/errors/GraphQLError.ts

import { ASTNode, GraphQLError as OriginalGraphQLError, Source } from "graphql";
import { Maybe } from "type-graphql";

type ErrorOptions = {
  nodes?: Maybe<ReadonlyArray<ASTNode> | ASTNode>;
  source?: Maybe<Source>;
  positions?: Maybe<ReadonlyArray<number>>;
  path?: Maybe<ReadonlyArray<string | number>>;
  originalError?: Maybe<Error>;
  extensions?: Maybe<{ [key: string]: any }>;
};

export class GraphQLError extends OriginalGraphQLError {
  constructor(message: string, options?: ErrorOptions) {
    const extensions = {
      ...(options?.originalError && {
        originalError: options?.originalError,
      }),
      ...(options?.extensions && {
        ...options?.extensions,
      }),
    };
    super(
      message,
      options?.nodes,
      options?.source,
      options?.positions,
      options?.path,
      options?.originalError,
      extensions
    );
  }
}
```

So I use this instead of the one from `graphql`.

Also notice that I have to put `originalError` into `extensions` object,
`graphql-yoga` throws an error if `originalError` is not existed.

Usage:

```
// SomewhereResolver.ts

async destroyDbMutation(){
   try{
      const ok = await businessRequirement.destroyDB();
      return ok;
   }catch(error:any){
      throw new GraphQLError(error.message, { originalError: error });
   }
}
```